# Error after deleting Images.xcassets by mistake, objective-c and xcode6.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

Accidentally I deleted the Images.xcassets folder in my app, and I tried to add a new one instead but I got a weird error :

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'AudioToolbox' (I guess it doesn't matter which library, it gives error on the first one and in my case it was AudioToolBox)

I tried to delete derived data folder but didn't work, and I made sure that the AudioToolbox is there as well.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: try to add library path in HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS.

Comment: This is a wake-up call to use Git, backups and a remote Git repository. Don't ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your .xcasset directory is in your "Copy Bundle Resources" on the Build Phases section of your project settings. Then clean the project (Cmd + K) then build it. Should work.